# What smoke detector fits this bracket

Tags: smoke-detectors

There is an empty bracket for a smoke detector in the hallway. See picture. What brand/model of detector uses that kind of bracket?

[image]

Comment: When you buy a new one it will come with a new bracket

Comment: Just loosen the two screws and place that bracket in the round file cabinet.

Comment: Probably an obsolete one. Follow Kris's advice.

Comment: smoke detectors are only good for at most 10 years - get a new one.

Comment: Unless you have a box full of smoke detectors that aren't mounted, this bracket is of limited use, at best. If you _do_ have a box full of uninstalled smoke detectors, keep trying different ones until one fits.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I was more curious if was a smoke alarm or CO alarm. I do not have the alarm that screwed into that mounting bracket. I'm guessing it was CO because there are smoke detectors 5 feet away from whatever used to be here.